# KCFinder & Ckeditor PDF file corupt upload issues

Tags: file-upload, upload, ckeditor, kcfinder

When we upload PDF using KCfinder on our CKeditor package the file somehow converts to an image or the pdf file gets corrupted. Cannot be open. Anyone experience this same issue and found a fix?

PHP Version 5.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my own question. If anybody else has this issue please see below.

The problem seems to be that with PHP 5.4 Imagick and Magick Wand. What I did was disabled Imagick, and Magick Wand from the PHP Settings.

Then in KCFinder config file (conf/config.php) changed line 45 from

```
'imageDriversPriority' => "imagick gmagick gd",
```

to

```
'imageDriversPriority' => "gd",
```

You may get away with just editing the KCFinder config file and leaving the php settings alone. I hope this was helpful.

Comment: In my case, I solved it by commenting out `filenameChangeChars`. Suggested solutions did not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to avoid resizing images.

In KCFinder config file (conf/config.php) set lines

```
'maxImageWidth' => 0,
'maxImageHeight' => 0,
```